# papyrus installation

Tags: installation, windows-7

I have some question about papyrus ;

- How can I install papyrus uml to my 64 bit system (*Windows 7, **NOT** Ubuntu!*)?
- can you give the steps ?

I have tried what is told in the papyrus uml website but I could not manage.

Answer (score 0):

Because Papyrus UML doesn't have 64 bit version, first install the 32bit support on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

After that:

```
wget http://www.papyrusuml.org/home/liblocal/docs/Papyrus/1.12/papyrus-1.12.0/RCPs/Papyrus-1.12.3-linux32.x86.tar.bz2
```

Followed by:

```
tar xvfj Papyrus-1.12.3-linux32.x86.tar.bz2
```

Step into the extracted directory:

```
cd papyrus-1.12.3
```

And finally, run it:

```
./papyrus
```

**NOTE**

I will not delete the answer, but the question was referring to Win7. Perhaps it will help someone with Ubuntu as well.

Comment: How to run on windows 7

Comment: On Windows 7? Nothing special, download the Windows version, and install it! It should work. Also please note, that this site is for helping people with Ubuntu, and not Windows!